# How do I move an svg node from one group to another?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Suppose I have the following document:

```
<svg>
    <g id='a'>
        <rect id='foo'/>
    </g>
    <g id='b'></g>
</svg>
```

How do I **move** my foo rectangle from group `#a` to group `#b`? Preferably with d3 but native JS works too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
function setParent(el, newParent) {
    newParent.appendChild(el);
}

setParent(document.getElementById('foo'), document.getElementById('b'));
```